# proof that equalizer of f and g is an isomorphism if f = g

Tags: category-theory

I found a proposition and a proof in *Categorical Closure Operators* by Gabriele Castellini saying that:

> Let $E \xrightarrow{e} X$, and $f, g : X \rightarrow Y$ be morphisms
> such that $e$ is an equalizer of $f$ and $g$. Then $d$ is an
> isomorphism if and only if $f=g$.

I understand the $\Rightarrow$ direction, but I'm not sure about the other way, showing if $f=g$, then $e$ is an isomorphism.

The proof in the book says the following:

> If $f=g$, then $id_X$ satisfies $f \circ id_X = g \circ id_x$.
> Consequently, by definition of equalizer, there is a morphism $X
>  \xrightarrow{t} E$ such that $ e \circ t = id_x$. Hence, e is a
> monomorphism and a retraction and so an isomorphism.

Specifically, why is there a morphism $X \xrightarrow{t} E$ such that $ e \circ t = id_x$? I don't think that's a part of the definition of being an equalizer. Any guidance on how to understand this part?

Edit:
The definition of equalizer that I am using is the following:

An equalizer of a parallel pair of maps $f, g \rightrightarrows B$ in a cat $\mathbb{C}$ consists of an object E and an arrow $e: E \rightarrow A $ such that (1) $f \circ e = g \circ e$ (2) (the universal mapping property part) For all $h : X \rightarrow A$ with $f \circ h = g \circ h$, there exists a unique $m: X \rightarrow E$ with $e \circ m = h $

Comment: Would you mind adding your source texts' definition of equaliser? The existence of $t$ is given directly and immediately by the equaliser condition on my reading.

Comment: I added the definition of equalizer to the question. Does my definition imply the part I'm asking about?

Comment: Great! so the existence of $t$ is given by the universal mapping property in the case that $h: = 1_X$, noting that $f \circ h = f = g = g\circ h$. Here we used the fact that $f = g$ by hypothesis and $h$ is an identity map.

Comment: Oooh I see.. Thank you so much! You can also add your comment as the answer (if that's something allowed) so I that I can endorse(?) it. (Not sure about the lingo, I'm a new contributor)

Comment: That is something that is allowed, thanks for trying to be conscious of the rules of Math SE, and welcome! I will type up a short proof for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the map $h: X \to X$ given by $1_X$ satisfies equation $(1)$:

$$
\begin{align}
f \circ h &= f & \text{by identity axiom}\\
&= g &\text{by hypothesis }\\
&= g \circ h. & \text{by identity axiom} \tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
As $f \circ h = g \circ h$, it is then immediate by the universal mapping property that there is some (unique) $t:X \to E$ such that $e \circ t = h$. By definition of $h$ then $e \circ t = 1_X$. As required.